# angularjs: filtering with chosen control

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

[Not Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKMZM/11/)

Any idea why the filtering is not kicking in?  I was expecting to see ninja cat selected in the controller similar to [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKMZM/10/).

```
var app = angular.module( 'catapp', [ 'localytics.directives' ] );

app.directive('petConverter', function() {
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(valueFromModel){
                    var target1 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < valueFromModel.length; i++) {
                        target1.push(valueFromModel[i].type);
                    }
                    return target1;
            });
        }
    }
});

app.controller( 'CatController', function ( $scope ) {


    $scope.lol = { cats: [
        'longcat',
        'ninjacat',
        'monorail cat'
    ]};

    $scope.myModel = [{type:'ninjacat'}];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There were quite few typos in the directive and I resolved them in the fiddle and here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKMZM/6/)

Updated Directive code:

```
.directive('petConverter', function() {
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(valueFromModel){
                    //add this line
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(valueFromModel[0]);
                    var target1 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < valueFromModel.length; i++) {
                        target1.push(valueFromModel[i].type);
                    }
                    return target1;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wKMZM/12/)

Comment: Thx v31 for looking into this.  I updated my question based on typos you identified.  Bit new to jsfiddle had wrong links, now its updated.  Thank again!

Comment: Typos were only the interim problem, the main problem still remains :(.

Comment: @ragche: now added an updated fiddle and the code has a comment in which I added a line ngModel.$setViewValue(valueFromModel[0]); hope that helps now

Comment: While I can write a loop to do explicit setViewValue for all the values in the model, I was trying to see how I can use filter to get the UI updated automatically.